# how to get using GoogleMap source and target?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying create a how to get using GoogleMap. I want trace route of source and target. To do it I have source and target positions with Longitude and Latitude. To do it I created 2 attributes. `source and target` source is my location and target is where I want to go.

How can I do it ? How can I trace the route in GoogleMap ?

```
public class FormComoChegarEmpresa extends Fragment{
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName() + "->";
    private static Empresa empresa;


    //latitude longitude
    private Double sourceLat, sourceLong;
    private Double targetLat, targetLong;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.como_chegar_empresa, container, false);

        if(getArguments().getSerializable("empresa") != null){
            empresa = (Empresa)getArguments().getSerializable("empresa");
            targetLat = empresa.getEndereco().getLatitude();
            targetLong = empresa.getEndereco().getLongitude();
        }

        mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        map = mapView.getMap();
        if(map != null){
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            //my location
            sourceLat = map.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
            sourceLong = map.getMyLocation().getLongitude();

            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(sourceLat,
                    sourceLong), 10);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }


        return  view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to draw a line between **source** & **destination**, you can use **[This Labrary](https://github.com/jd-alexander/google-directions-android)**

If you want start camera animation from **source** to **destination**, I'm not sure your code is correct or not! Just I think you should pass **destination** into **cameraUpdate**, not **source** ...

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(targetLat, targetLong), 10);
```

Comment: very nice ...I'll try this library

Comment: do you know how could I add this project library in Android Studio ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva! Unfortunately, I use Eclipse and don't know how you can import it in Android Studio !!! But I know that you can create new project and copy files of this library into your new project ... Then use this project as library for your project

Comment: I'm trying add this library in my project with Android Studio but doesn't works. I'll really really happy if you can help me.

Comment: You should add google_play_service library as dependency to this library.
This library works for me in Eclipse. Please let me know your problem ...